# How to run multiple test (Regression and Sanity Test) from one project in nunit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm new to nunit.  I worked with testng test runner before.  Right now the code is written in C#, Selenium and using nunit test runner using Visual studio 2017.

I'm planning to create categories(labels) for Regression and Sanity.

- How to run each category separately from one project ?
- Does nunit has similar way as testng.xml group(where we can define the group to run the tests. ex: if I want Regression to run then I can just use the group name Regression and it will run all the tests which has the group name regression)
  Following is the testng example:

  ```
  <suite name="Sample Suite">
    <test name="testing">
       <groups>
         <run>
           <include name="Regression"/>
         </run>
       </groups>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.example.group.groupExamples" />
    </classes>
   </test>
  </suite>
  ```
- Where does this nunit test runner running the test from the foldering stucture (means any seperate file or XML or only from main?

I hope my questions are clear.